# Online trading testing sandbox for Bittrex

Tags: bittrex

Is there any testing Sandbox for Bitrrex? How can I obtain the test bitcoin and purchase the ETH? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Bittrex has a sandbox mode, I googled it and there wasnt so much information around...

You can look for testnets and testnet coins faucets if you want to test cryptos without spending real money.